# Integer representing a DATETIME value: how to convert?

Tags: sql-server

I have an integer field as containing a represent DATETIME value,
how to can convert a  datetime format..

the value,  represent datetime

```
6843438  is a    04/01/2013 09:18
6843660  is a   04/01/2013 13:00
```

try to

```
select dateadd(hour,6843438,'19700101') -->>  error
select dateadd(hour,843438,'19700101') -->> 2066-03-21 06:00:00.000  is bad
```

any idea?

Comment: Why are you using an integer field to start with? Why isn't it a datetime field? Can you change the schema to be more sensible?

Comment: probably not the best way to stored DateTime values in the first place!

Comment: @swasheck The OP's epoch is January 1, 2000.

Answer (score 5):

Well, it isn't hours because you get 09:18. So it's probably minutes.

We can verify that thus, and also work our roughly how many years there are

```
SELECT
    6843438 /60 /24 /365,    --years = 13
    6843438 /60,             --hours = 114957 (not really useful)
    6843438 % 60             --minutes = 18
```

So, if you change the Epoch to 01 Jan 2000, it works

```
select
    dateadd(minute,6843438,'20000101'),
    dateadd(minute,6843660,'20000101')
```